# Clarification regarding usage of bundle

Tags: android, textview, bundle

Please can you help out with this: I pass a bundle via an intent and need to display it on a textview,but I am unable to get any display on my textview. The code is :

Intent part of the code:

```
if(result != null)
{
    Intent tokenIntent = new Intent(mContext, tokenActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("responsedata",result);

    tokenIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(tokenIntent);
}
```

Activity receiving the intent:

```
TextView response;
Bundle bundle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    response=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.texter);
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    response.setText(bundle.getString("responsedata"));
    //  sampletext.setText(result);
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you pass the bundle to the intent

Comment: Weird! Please check the string you retrieve if it's null or just empty !

Comment: You have to print a string value in logcat..

Comment: @Pavlos The textview is still blank.

Comment: @PiyushGupta I would like to check the functionality of the intent, bundle by printing it on the second activity's textview. Can you tell me how logcat is relevant ?

Comment: I have not figured it out yet.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in your intent part of code,use this:

```
tokenIntent.putExtra("responsedata",result);
```

and remove this part:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("responsedata",result);
tokenIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Let me know if it's ok.

Comment: It wont be okay because in that case he has to retrieve the String through the intent and no tthrough the Bundle!

Comment: Did you tried to set text directly in code, to see if it's not a problem with the view ?
Also make sure that you're not writing in TextView with the same color of its backgroud.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs guys, I defined a textview in xml referred by it's id "texter" and referred it in the java code. There is no issue with the background too, it is something to do with bundle/intent passing.

Comment: I have not figured it out yet.Any help would be appreciated.